# Как обернуть код на питонее в доступную оболчку

Tags: python

Всем привет,
у меня есть написаный на питоне код о сравнении 2х файлов эксель, теперь мне нужно сделать его доступным для человека, не умеющего работать с JupyterNotebook. Хотелось бы отделаться малой кровью и сделать это наиболее простым образом(без написания фронтенда в привычном образе). Кто-то может подсказать план действий?

От пользователя требуется только загрузить файлы эксель и на выходе нужно получить файл эксель со сравнением.
Пока что есть одна идея сделать это с помощью flask. Но я не уверена, что это наилучший путь.

Comment: Либо web api либо докер, наверное

Comment: Опишите в вопросе сценарий взаимодействия пользователя с вашей программой. Без этого трудно дать рекомендации по интерфейсу пользователя.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy написала.

Comment: Выбор двух файлов - понятно. Затем вычисления. Затем что-то показывается пользователю. Что именно? Чуть больше деталей. Кроме демонстрации результата на экране программа его (результат) куда-нибудь сохраняет? (Добавьте все ответы в вопрос, пожалуйста.)

Comment: Можно попробовать [streamlit](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit). Если не подойдет - используйте те средства, с которыми лучше всего знакомы: например, если веб, то веб. Я когда-то делал подобную задачу на Tkinter, т.к. лучше всего его знаю.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy добавила, вычисления я и не хотела добавлять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы можете установить Питон на компьютер пользователя, то этот скрипт попросит пользователя выбрать три файла и выполнит работу над ними. В данном случае он склеивает первые два файла и записывает их в третий:

```
import tkinter.filedialog


def process(filename_1, filename_2, filename_3):
    with open(filename_3, 'w') as f3:
        with open(filename_1) as f1:
            for line in f1:
                print(line, end='', file=f3)
        with open(filename_2) as f2:
            for line in f2:
                print(line, end='', file=f3)


def main():

    filename_1 = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select first file')
    if not isinstance(filename_1, str):
        return

    filename_2 = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select second file')
    if not isinstance(filename_2, str):
        return

    filename_3 = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title='Select file for result')
    if not isinstance(filename_3, str):
        return

    process(filename_1, filename_2, filename_3)


main()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

мне кажется проще сделать через cgi, примерно так, тремя файлами

`test_dir/start_http_server.py` - запуск http сервера

```
import http.server
httpd = http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer(('192.168.1.1', 80), http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()  # http://192.168.1.1:80
```

`test_dir/cgi-bin/index.html` - стартовая страница, с формой загрузки файлов

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.py" method="post">
    <p>File: <input type="upload_file" name="upload_file"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="upload_file"></p>
</form>
</html>
```

`test_dir/cgi-bin/upload_file.py` - сравнение файлов и выгрузка файла клиенту, запускается кнопкой субмит на стартовой странице

```
import cgi

def main(file_path):
    """код о сравнении 2х файлов эксел"""
    result_file_link = '...'
    return result_file_link

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # получение исходного файла
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    file_1 = form['upload_file']
    # получение файла результата
    result_file_link = main(file_1.filename)
    # передача файла результата, то что выведет print, попадет клиенту в браузер
    print(f'''
        Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="{result_file_link}"
        Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="{result_file_link}"
        Content-Length: " + {os.stat(result_file_link).st_size}
        
            {open(result_file_link, 'rb').read()}
    ''')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Ну если человеку код нужен просто в пользование, то я бы просто все обернул в функции, которые потом достаточно было бы вызвать с нужными входными данными. Если же ему нужно дальше развивать, то проще уж ему будет вкурить в Jupiter, не так он и сложен. Нельзя же сделать понятной программу, если человек не понимает ее основного инструмента.

Comment: А дальше что, после оборачивания в функции? Нужно же как-то фронтенд сделать

Comment: @Elena Barbanova Вам нужен пользовательский интерфейс?

Comment: Сравнение 2 эксель файлов не обязательно требует сложного фронтенда. Все зависит от того, кому нужна программа, как он ей хочет пользоваться. Можно и в консоли таким кодом успешно пользоваться. Хотя я конечно не знаю о тонкостях вашей программы и о том, как и что она там сравнивает.

Comment: человеку не надо делать понятной программу. ему нужно отдать два файла и получить результат их сравнения. Вы точно понимаете, о чем говорите или просто решили ответ запостить?

Comment: @strawdog Непонятен вопрос был с начала. Если человеку нужен просто результат, нужно сделать другой интерфейс пользовательский, я это и сказал в комментарии. Либо консоль, либо что помудренее, зависит от желания кодера и хотения пользователя

Comment: @Manul74 да именно он

Comment: @Elena Barbanova  Qt, PyQt, Tkinter?  если это простое сравнивание и чуть управления можно сделать через консоль(коммандная строка).  типа myprg.py file1.xls file2.xls -t  ....

Comment: @Manul74 сравнивание не простое, программу сравнивания , используя пандас я уже написала, сейчас пробую flask для оборачивания